# How can I make this row of components responsive in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, bootstrap-5, responsive, responsiveness

This should be simple; I don't know what I'm overlooking. I am trying to have three ProjectCard components display as a single horizontal row on desktop and a single vertical column on mobile. Right now they just layer on top of each other on mobile so that I can only see one ProjectCard on top. How can I fix this so that they are in a vertical column on mobile? I'll provide the code for the cards themselves, the bigger component they are part of, and my CSS file with relevant styles.

ProjectCard.js:

```
import him from '../images/projects/him.jpg'

const placeholder = {
    name: 'placeholder',
    imageUrl: him,
};

export const ProjectCard = () => {
    return(
        
        <div>
            <div className="hovercontainer h-auto w-auto">
                <img src={placeholder.imageUrl} className="projectimage img-fluid"/>
                <div className="overlay">
                    <div className="hovertext">
                        <div id="projectaboutrow">
                            <h5 id="project-title">Project title</h5>
                            <h10 id="project-info" className="mb-2">Card subtitle</h10>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row toolsused">
                            <ul className="list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                                <li><span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">tool 1</span></li>
                                <li><span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">tool 2</span></li>
                                <li><span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">tool 3</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row" id="buttonrow">
                            <div className="col">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary pinkbutton" href="#">demo</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary pinkbutton" href="#">repo</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
};
```

ProjectPage.js:

```
import { ProjectCard } from './ProjectCard.js';
import { useSlideInFromBottom } from '../Hooks/UseSlideInFromBottom';


export const ProjectPage = () => {
    useSlideInFromBottom();

    return (
        <div id="projectpage" className="container vh-100 w-100 mx-auto mb-5 slide-in-bottom">

            <div className="row align-items-center mb-4">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <h1 id="projectlink">Projects</h1>
                </div>

                <div className="pixelfont col-md-8 align-self-center">
                    <h10>
                        see more at my <a href="#">portfolio gallery</a>!
                    </h10>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="projectcards" className="row flex-column flex-md-row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 g-3">
                <div className="col">
                    <ProjectCard />
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    <ProjectCard />
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    <ProjectCard />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};
```

App.css:

```
/* ============ PROJECT CARD HOVER EFFECT ============= */
.hovercontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

}

.projectimage {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.overlay {
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.hovercontainer:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.hovertext {
  opacity: 100%;
  color: var(--main-neutral);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}


/* ========== PROJECT CARD STYLING ========= */

#project-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--main-neutral);
}

#project-info {
  color: var(--main-neutral);
}

.badge-pill {
  background-color: var(--main-neutral);
  color: var(--secondary-neutral);
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

I have tried changing the image size/display type, changing the max-width of the .hovercontainer, and adding .img-fluid. I've tried a bunch of other things as well, but I can't remember all of them. I've played around with different row/col configurations as well. My efforts have resulted in either a layered stack of cards that overlap each other, or a vertical row of cards that visually extends into my AboutMe component (the next component rendered after ProjectPage in my App.js file) and gets overlapped by the AboutMe content.

Comment: adding "col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" to the ProjectCard cols in the ProjectPage component doesn't work and produces the layered effect as well